# Where does the 'divides' sign come from?

Tags: notation, math-history

When $a$ divides $b$ we say $a | b$. Where does the $|$ sign come from?

This is not homework, just personal interest in the history of mathematical language.

Comment: Maybe it developed from the notation used for long division, which seems less arbitrary (since it's used to help lay out a process neatly) than $a|b$

Comment: I love intelligent questions that nobody who reads them on the internet seems to know the answer to!

Comment: ...and therefore I have offered a bounty from my meagre stock of reputation points.

Comment: Have a look here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12459/who-introduced-the-divisibility-symbol-a-vert-b-a-divides-b-and-when

Comment: Scanning through A History of Mathematical Notations, the vertical stroke symbol $\mid$ seems to have had many uses. For example, $A\mid B$ meant $A=B$ for Reyher (1698), and for Christoff Rudolff (1525) it was a decimal separatrix, e.g. $65\mid 2\equiv 65.2$. Barlow (1845) used an italic $f$ rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise (let's use $\backsim$) to denote "divisible by," which is probably most related to the modern meaning of $\mid$, e.g. $a\mid b\equiv b\backsim a$. But as the linked to answers point out its quite a modern notation I think.

Comment: See my question on a related notion too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387906/when-was-the-notation-pa-mid-mid-b-first-introduced-roughly

Comment: Thanks, @DavidScholz. Conifold's answer is highly informative and deserves the bounty. I hope your "||" question gets an answer of similar quality, Pixel.