# When was the notation $p^a\mid\mid b$ first introduced (roughly)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

We may write $a$ divides $b$ more succinctly as $a\mid b$. A useful development of this notation is $p^a\mid\mid b$ where $p$ is prime, and means that $a$ is the highest power of $p$ such that $p^a\mid b$. Does anybody know when this second notation was first introduced? Is it an old-ish notation or more recent?

Comment: I didn't find either $\mid$ or $\mid\mid$ in Cajori's "A History of Mathematical Notations".